# Received "Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option" error

Tags: java

After I created a new class in netbeans, I received "Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option" error trying to debug the new class. I deleted that class, and decided to use a different class, which was not anyway related to the previously deleted class, that worked perfectly with the debugger yesterday. I also receive this error, and it appears that this issue is permanent. I have gone through some related posts, but they do not appear to have the same issue. I have checked to make sure "generate Debugging info" was checked, and it was.

What causes this error, and why is it now permanent regardless of the class I try to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [javac -g options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCGAJDC), especially `-g` and `-g:none`.

If you use a build infrastructure like **maven** or **gradle** then there might be something wrong.

But for NetBeans itsef look at the compiler options.
Go to the **Project Properties** (not global options), where the checkbox "Generate Debugging info" should be checked.

There also is a text field "Additional Compiler options" that should normally be empty.

Do a clean build.

*I must admit, that the behaviour there almost looks like project garbage. But more to be expected from eclipse than NetBeans.*

---

As the mention is of *"Variable information not available,"* it seems
the option `-g:vars` is wanted for some reason (some class manipulating library,
documentation tool, annotation processing). Check whether you installed some NetBeans plugin in that area. By default debug information on variables is not added, as for exceptions the other two suffice.

Additional compiler options: **-g:source,lines,vars**

Comment: +eggen, what do you mean by project garbage? Also I just did a clean-build, but it did not appear do anything. I still have the same issue. In the debugger window I have "Methodbreakpoint [java.lang.Object].clone "()Ljava/lang/Object;' successfully submitted. Method breakpoint hit in java.lang.Object.clone on line ? by thread main.

Comment: There was not anything in the text field "additional Compiler options"

Comment: I have reinstalled netbeans and JDK  and I still get the same error regardless which file I use.

Comment: I have added the explicit mention of `-g:vars`. With a bit of luck that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I ended up reinstalling netbeans and JDK separately. It seems to do the trick. It is weird how one day I was able to use the debugger no problem, but the following I end up with that error. I did not change any settings.

Comment: In regards to whether I installed any plugins, I did not. The netbeans I had previously was the base version. Just weird it happened. Thanks for the suggestions and hopefully this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  For me it was because I'd created a new (completely empty) Java project under the default `NetBeansProject` folder and then added a *pre-existing* source folder to the project, which was located somewhere else.

1. Right-click project --> Properties --> Sources --> Source Package Folders
2. Remove any extraneous/empty folders.
3. Click OK and try debugging the project again.

*I'd created a separate project folder to house all of NetBeans' meta junk (so that it wouldn't contaminate my real project folder).*